adding spaces to a text file to a specific character in python
I know this is probably an easy one but I am still new to Python and need a  little push in the right direction.  I have a text file that I need a certain number of spaces where on character 88 an N is placed going on to the new line.  The test file I am using looks like this:
aaaa                                                 aaaaa

What my desired output (for testing) would look like where a N appears at a specific character.
aaa     N
aaaa    N

With my coding I am getting the output looking like this:
aaa      N
aaaa      N

I have tried to manually code it (no if statements) but get the output above:
newf=""
with open('testfile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        
        newf+=line.strip()+"      N\n"
    f.close()
with open('testfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(newf)
    f.close()

I have tried an if statement but keep getting errors
The indentation error is not the issue that I am having, what I am trying to do is append a text file to add spaces at the end of text and put a N at a specfic space (88) so if the text was A then 87 spaces then N, if the next line is AA then 86 spaces with N.

if you're getting an indentation error, why don't you just indent the next line...?

Aside: with closes the file. No need for f.close()

What do you mean by "character 88"? In ASCII, that's X, or your example doesn't show 88 characters in a line

I am trying to get the text file to where it would put an 8 at character 88 so for example if the text file was A then put 87 spaces with a N at space 88  and if the next line is AA then 86 spaces then N

I'm guessing the formatting of your example is wrong, and it should actually be two lines? But then this is a duplicate of another common duplicate; how to pad a string with spaces to a specific width. I'll add that as a second duplicate.

Use a \t character instead in order to use a tab and have them line up as such
newf+=line.strip()+"\tN\n"

